# JQuery: use element's html() (innerHTML) as a parameter to canvas's drawSvg method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, canvg

I am trying to convert/ put an SVG into a canvas using the drawSvg() function. The command is: `ctx.drawSvg(SVG_XML_OR_PATH_TO_SVG, dx, dy, dw, dh);`. This works fine when I specifically put the svg in as a parameter, for example: `ctx.drawSvg('<svg><rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="red" /></svg>', 0 , 0 , 500, 500);`, I end up with a canvas that has a red square in it, which is exactly correct. However, I need to be able to take the Svg tag from the document and use that as a parameter. I've tried a few different methods to do this but none of them work. How can I do it?
Here is a jsFiddle page with what I am trying to do. Thanks!
http://jsfiddle.net/qDmhV/722/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.html()` returns an element's innerHTML including leading and trailing whitespace, which `drawSvg()` chokes on.

Try this ([from your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qDmhV/723/)):

```
ctx.drawSvg($.trim($("#test2").html()), 0 , 0 , 500, 500);
```

`$.trim` will remove that whitespace for you.